# Error: Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelStore

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem on my Android project, I can't build, this is the error I have:

Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelStore

Anybody know how to solve this problem?

This error occurs when I add implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'

this is my build.gradle`code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.merta.cricket"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using old versions, to solve this you can update all firebase dependencies and the google service plugin also.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

---

Another solution, since you are using firebaseui `2.3.0`, you need to update the firebase dependencies to the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.2.0'
```

Check this for more info:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/version-2.3.0#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries

Comment: keep them at 11.0.4 and downgrade the firebaseui to 2.2.0

Comment: I downgraded the firebaseui to 2.1.1 and the error went. Thanks a lot.